# Boxplot facet grid sharing x variable (string) with one column, multiple rows

Tags: python-2.7, seaborn, boxplot

So I want to build a table of Boxplots where each row is a y variable, and all plots share the same x variable. I've got 7 variables I want to represent as boxplots in the y that all share the same grouping in the X as another variable, so basically a facetgrid of boxplots with 7 rows, 1 column all sharing the x.

I've tried working through the facetgrid documentation and end up with things plotting on top of each other, rather than each of the subplots. The code is below for a test with 2 variables

So the first attempt is this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('MyData.csv')

fig, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(2,1)

ax1 = sns.boxplot(x="Group", y="Var1", data=df, showfliers=False, orient='v')

ax2 = sns.boxplot(x="Group", y="Var2", data=df, showfliers=False, orient='v')
```

Which results in plotting things on top of each other:

[image]

So trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52472757/creating-a-boxplot-facetgrid-in-seaborn-for-python) answer the code is:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1)
axes=axes.flatten()

ax = sns.boxplot(x="Group", y="Var1", data=df, showfliers=False, orient='v', ax=axes[0,0])

ax = sns.boxplot(x="Group", y="Var2", data=df, showfliers=False, orient='v', ax=axes[1,0])
```

Which returns `IndexError: too many indices for array`and a blank plot:

[image]

If anyone can help that would be great! Also if you can help with sharing the X so that the plots don't repeat their x axis 7 times and are instead joined together that would help a lot!

Comment: You need to be a bit more structured. The first approach would work if you used the axes instead of assigning them, i.e. `sns.boxplot(...., ax=ax1)` instead of `ax1 = sns.boxplot(...)`. The second approach would work if you used `axes[0]` instead of `axes[0,0]`. All of this is not related to a `FacetGrid`, so is the question how to use a `FacetGrid` or why your attempts fail?

Comment: That works fine. I guess I also meant to ask how to do this via a facet grid, but now that I can get it to work with mpl subplots I think its fine.

Comment: Meant to say thanks a lot btw! :)